# How to widen a standard string while maintaining the characters?

Tags: c++11, stdstring, wchar-t

I have a function to take a `std::string` and change it into a `wchar_t*`. My current widen function looks like this

```
wchar_t* widen(const std::string& str){  
    wchar_t * dest = new wchar_t[str.size()+1];
    char * temp = new char[str.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<str.size();i++)
        dest[i] = str[i];
    dest[str.size()] = '\0';
    return dest;
}
```

This works just fine for standard characters, however (and I cannot believe this hasn't been an issue before now) when I have characters like á, é, í, ó, ú, ñ, or ü it breaks and the results are vastly different.
Ex: my `str` comes in as `"Database Function: áFákéFúnctíóñü"`
But `dest` ends up as: `"Database Function: ￡F￡k￩F￺nct￭￳￱￼"`

How can I change from a `std::string` to a `wchar_t*` while maintaining international characters?

Comment: Just a note on your code: In most cases, when you're using manual memory management (i.e. not using smart pointers) or when you are using the vector `new`, you are doing something wrong. Use standard containers (vector, string, wstring) here.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, appreciate the note. This particular project is between 10-14 years old in most places, I've only been blessed to wade through it for the past year or so, and even more unfortunately, due to backwards compatibility necessity I can't fix old stuff that is broken

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: You can't.

Longer answer: `std::string` contains `char` elements which typically contain ASCII in the first 127 values, while everything else ("international characters") is in the values above (or the negative ones, if `char` is signed). In order to determine the according representation in a `wchar_t` string, you first need to know the encoding in the source string (could be ISO-8859-15 or even UTF-8) and the one in the target string (often UTF-16, UCS2 or UTF-32) and then transcode accordingly.

Comment: Yes, "know the encoding in the source string…and the one in the target string…and then transcode accordingly." This makes any similarity to ASCII—and even the existence of ASCII—irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if the source is using old ANSI code page or UTF8. For ANSI code page, you have to know the locale, and use `mbstowcs`. For UTF8 you can make a conversion to UTF16 using `codecvt_utf8_utf16`. However `codecvt_utf8_utf16` is deprecated and it has no replacement as of yet. In Windows you can use WinAPI function to make the conversions more reliably.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>

std::wstring widen(const std::string& src)
{
    int len = src.size();
    std::wstring dst(len + 1, 0);
    mbstowcs(&dst[0], src.c_str(), len);
    return dst;
}

int main()
{
    //ANSI code page?
    std::string src = "áFákéFúnctíóñü";
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en"); //English assumed
    std::wstring dst = widen(src);
    std::wcout << dst << "\n";

    //UTF8?
    src = u8"áFákéFúnctíóñü";
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t> convert;
    dst = convert.from_bytes(src);
    std::wcout << dst << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a Windows solution, here's some utility functions I use based on the wisdom of http://utf8everywhere.org/

```
/// Convert a windows UTF-16 string to a UTF-8 string
///
/// @param s[in] the UTF-16 string
/// @return std::string UTF-8 string
inline std::string Narrow(std::wstring_view wstr) {
  if (wstr.empty()) return {};
  int len = ::WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], wstr.size(), nullptr, 0,
                                  nullptr, nullptr);
  std::string out(len, 0);
  ::WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], wstr.size(), &out[0], len,
                        nullptr, nullptr);
  return out;
}

/// Convert a UTF-8 string to a windows UTF-16 string
///
/// @param s[in] the UTF-8 string
/// @param n[in] the UTF-8 string's length, or -1 if string is null-terminated
/// @return std::wstring UTF-16 string
inline std::wstring Widen(std::string_view str) {
  if (str.empty()) return {};
  int len = ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], str.size(), NULL, 0);
  std::wstring out(len, 0);
  ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], str.size(), &out[0], len);
  return out;
}
```

Usually used inline in windows API calls like:

```cpp
std::string message = "Hello world!";
::MessageBoxW(NULL, Widen(message).c_str(), L"Title", MB_OK);
```

A cross-platform and possibly faster solution could be found by exploring Boost.Nowide's conversion functions: https://github.com/boostorg/nowide/blob/develop/include/boost/nowide/utf/convert.hpp